# How do I make it so an image set to background-size: cover cooperates with windows window size increasing and decreasing

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I'm a begginer javascript developer and I am working on a digital clock program, but I wanted it to look more interesting so I generated this background image with AI tools of a vintage clock and I made it so the actual clock element is overlayed on the image so it looks like a 3d clock.

As you can see in my code the background image is set to "cover" in order to fit the window size and I made it so the clock is exactly in the middle to avoid problems with the clock element moving when resizing the window. However, now I am running into a problem because whenever I resize the window the clock element increases and decreases in size when the background image stays the same. How can I make it so the background image will somehow cover the window but also logically zoom in and out to fit the clock element?

[Here's how its supposed to always look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP6Jz.jpg)

[And here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYSQZ.jpg)

Here is my code:

```css
body, html {
    overflow: hidden;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif; 
}
.mainDiv{
    background-image: url(terabedzie.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#grainEffect {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    left: -50%;
    top: -50%; 
    background-image: url(Png333.png);
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    animation: grain 1.5s steps(6) infinite;
}

@keyframes grain {
    0%, 100% {transform: translate(0,0);}
    10% {transform: translate(-10%,5%);}
    30% {transform: translate(11%,-8%);}
    50% {transform: translate(-2%,15%);}
    70% {transform: translate(9%,7%);}
    90% {transform: translate(-14%,17%);}
}



.clock{
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgb(31, 30, 30);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    perspective: 1000px;
    pointer-events: none;

 }

.clock span{
    font-size: 70px;
    transform: scaleY(2) rotateY(-17deg) rotateZ(2.7deg) rotateX(-16deg);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1.7px black;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Digital clock</title>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainDiv">
      <div id="grainEffect">
        <img id="grainImage" src="grainn22.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="clock">
       <span>20:00:00</span>  
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="digitalClock.js"></script>
</body>
```

Thanks for your help!

I tried assigning the background image as a pseudo element to the clock element but it didnt work, based of some other response to a question I also experimented with attaching the image as a  element in html as well as the background image in css but still the same.

Comment: Please edit your question to attach the background images referenced by your code, or better still, edit the code in your snippet to use images which are available on the web.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your snippet as a full page and adjust my window size, the digits stay a constant size. If that’s what you want, for the digits to stay a constant size, then *you need the background to also stay a constant size*. Use `background-size: 2000px` or whatever value makes the image the correct size with respect to your digits. You already have `background-position: center`, so your image will crop at the edges, which I assume is what you want.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif; 
  background-image: url(https://donald.au/bugs/so-77795599-1.webp);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 2000px;
}

.clock {
  display: flex;
  color: rgb(31, 30, 30);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  perspective: 1000px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.clock span {
  font-size: 70px;
  transform: scaleY(2) rotateY(-17deg) rotateZ(2.7deg) rotateX(-16deg);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1.7px black;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="clock">
  <span>20:00:00</span>  
</div>
```

However, if what you actually want is for your digits to scale proportionally with the window width (my preferred design), then you need to use `vw` units when specifying your `font-size`. Then for the background you’d use a percentage size like `background-size: 100%` or `150%`. Note that if you use a single value with `background-size`, it applies to the width, and the height will default to `auto`.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif; 
  background-image: url(https://donald.au/bugs/so-77795599-1.webp);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 150%;
}

.clock {
  display: flex;
  color: rgb(31, 30, 30);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  perspective: 1000px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.clock span {
  font-size: 6vw;
  transform: scaleY(2) rotateY(-17deg) rotateZ(2.7deg) rotateX(-16deg);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1.7px black;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="clock">
  <span>20:00:00</span>  
</div>
```

Make sure you use the **full page** link after running these snippets to test the responsiveness.